# 2 Sexy Content Content Localisation - DNN 9.02.00

Tags: dotnetnuke, multilingual, 2sxc

I have been trying to localise a site for one of my customers but it appears to be bugging out when I try to update the fields in another language.

The languages that I have on my site are the following

English,
Chinese

The site was built in English and is being localaised to Chinese hence using the 2sxc built in functionality.

The issue is that when I enter the title in the chinese section and save, it overwrites the english field and disables it and displays the Chinese information. I have to re-do the whole process twice to have it work and thats not working very well at the moment.

I am unsure if this is a bug but I thought i'd post it here and see if it is or not.

This error is coming up in the logs 6 times each refresh

```
AbsoluteURL:
DefaultDataProvider:DotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke
ExceptionGUID:02a03f54-e165-48be-b7ba-d7365e86a53c
AssemblyVersion:
PortalId:-1
UserId:-1
TabId:-1
RawUrl:
Referrer:
UserAgent:
ExceptionHash:3ftB22aJZ+wR3To+2W8aM9Iv0U4=
Message:Search: Error while indexing module 646 on tab 88, portal 0
StackTrace:
at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.DnnBusinessController.GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime beginDate) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2sxc Dnn\Environment\Dnn7\DnnBusinessController.cs:line 102 at DotNetNuke.Services.Search.ModuleIndexer.IndexSearchDocuments(Int32 portalId, ScheduleHistoryItem schedule, DateTime startDateLocal, Action`1 indexer)
InnerMessage:Error getting List of Stream. Stream Name: Default DataSource Name: EntityIdFilter
InnerStackTrace:
at ToSic.Eav.DataSources.DataStream.get_List() in C:\Projects\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.DataSources\DataStream.cs:line 122 at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.Search.SearchController.GetModifiedSearchDocuments(IInstanceInfo instance, DateTime beginDate) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2sxc Dnn\Search\SearchController.cs:line 101 at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.DnnBusinessController.GetModifiedSearchDocuments(ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime beginDate) in C:\Projects\2sxc-dnn742\Website\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2sxc Dnn\Environment\Dnn7\DnnBusinessController.cs:line 98
Source:ToSic.Sxc.Dnn
FileName:
FileLineNumber:0
FileColumnNumber:0
Method:
Server Name: KIERAN-PC
```

I have a video, how would you like me to show it to you?

Regards

Kieran

Comment: These are two separate things - best not mix them in one question. 
The ML is usually very reliable, so please post the link to the video here - and also please tell us the 2sxc version you're using.

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: Hello, I have just uploaded the video to Youtube. It may be intentionally working like that just doesnt seem like it :D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=la6L7hXSNdI

Comment: thx for the video. My guess is that it's a combination of original content not being marked EN (because it wasn't multi-language when the initial content was added), + a bug in the UI which doesn't handle this correctly.

Comment: Please create an issue on github. We can't prioritize it because other things are currently in the queue. If you need this soon, you'll need to get paid support - ca. 2-4h to fix this. For that, check https://2sxc.org/contact